# Can we show that $T^{\ast\ast}\subseteq T^\ast$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators

Let $H$ be a $\mathbb C$-Hilbert space and $T$ be a densely-defined linear operator on $H$.

> Can we show that $T^{\ast\ast}\subseteq T^\ast$?

It's clear to me that the claim is true when $T$ is symmetric (i.e. $T\subseteq T^\ast$), since then $T$ is closable, $\overline T$ is symmetric as well and hence $$T^{\ast\ast}=\overline T\subseteq\overline T^\ast=T^\ast\tag1.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $\newcommand{\iu}{\mathrm{i}}T = \iu I$, which is a bounded and everywhere defined operator (therefore also densely-defined). Then we have
\begin{align*}
T^{\ast} &= \overline{\iu}I= -\iu I \quad\text{and}\\
T^{\ast\ast} &= \overline{-\iu}I= \iu I.
\end{align*}
So $T^{\ast\ast} \cap T^{\ast} = \{0\}$.

Comment: What is $T^{\ast\ast}\cap T^\ast$ supposed to mean?

Comment: @MaoWao I imagine the points in the shared domain $D(T^{**})\cap D(T^*)$ on which $T^{**}$ and $T^*$ agree.

Comment: @MaoWao Linear operators are single-valued multi-valued linear operators which by definition are linear subspaces of the direct sum of their source and target spaces. So, it's clear what $T^{\ast\ast}\cap T^\ast$ is. Stated differently, it's simply the intersection of the corresponding graphs.

Comment: BTW, the claim in the question can be found here: http://www.math.lmu.de/~michel/closure_-_closed_ops.pdf. (Page 3, Comment (3))

Comment: @MaoWao every function regardless if it is linear or not is (by definition) a well defined relation between its domain and codomain. So the intersection of two function acting on the same spaces is always meaningful.
I guess if you don't have problems with $T \subseteq S$ (which appears in the question), you can also accept $T\cap S$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d it seems to me that the author forgot to mention that $T$ is symmetric. Otherwise a consequence would be that every $T$ is symmetric.